# VBA: save to PDF and send it with a specific title to pre-selected email addresses

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have the following code that saves to the current folder and opens the file:

```
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = Worksheets("mysheet")

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    strFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, From:=1, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=True

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

However, I do not want to open the file and want to send an email with the file as an attachment to some email addresses with a specified title on Outlook.

How can I do this?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How can I not open the file, and send the file as an attachment to a person with a specified title. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should look into using the Outlook object model.

Comment: I would like to send the saved PDF file, not the sheet.

Comment: This sort of thing is more than just a simple line of code or two. It would require an understanding of the Outlook Object model as mentioned by @roryap or use of CDO to send an email directly through SMTP. Answering your question would essentially amount to doing the work on your behalf, for that you need to do the research and do it yourself or hire a freelancer, not ask on a Q&A site. If you try yourself and run into problems feel free to ask about those specific problems here though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to open the file, then when you save it you should turn this to false:

```
OpenAfterPublish:=False '<-- in your code is now True
```

To send it as an attachment, you only need to attach the string you created:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
.to = "test@gmail.com"
.Subject = "Testfile"
.Body = "Hi"     
.Attachments.Add strFile
.Send  'Or use .Display to see the mail and send it manually
End With
```

Find more about usage of Outlook with Excel VBA [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm).